# Global variable not updating outside function

Tags: javascript

Trying to make variable created inside function possible to access globally, so far

```
console.log(proper_head);
```

constantly displays "1" while I need it to be updated every time the function is executed, here is my function:

```
var i = 0;
function change_head() {
    if (i < head_class.length) {
        head.classList.add(head_class[i].name);
        i++;
        var h = i;
        return h;
    } else if (i = 3) {
        head.className = "";
        i -= 3;
        var h = i;
        return h;
    }
}
var proper_head = change_head();
```

it is executed by pressing a button (not sure if it's important).
The only solution I came up with is to

```
 setTimeout()
```

I'm sure there is a better way.

Comment: `else if (i = 3) {` but `=` is assignment, not comparison...

Answer (score 0):

You could use a recursive implementation like this:

```
var i = 0;
function change_head() {
    if (i < head_class.length) {
        head.classList.add(head_class[i].name);
        i++;
        var h = i;
        return h;
    } else if (i = 3) {
        head.className = "";
        i -= 3;
        var h = i;
        return h;
    }
change_head();
}
```

The problem is that your function is only being called once, you can call the function from within itself, however the above example will never stop, and will probably hit the max call stack size in your browser and then crash, i would recommend wrapping it in some sort of if statement so that it stops at some point, e.g i > 50.

Edit:

I see what your actual problem is, neither of your if blocks are firing, after the first press, head_class.length === 1 so "if (i < head_class.length)" wont fire, it's also not equal to 3 for the else block so nothing happens, the else block also has an error, try changing it to this:

```
if (i < 3) {
        head.classList.add(head_class[i].name);
        i++;
        var h = i;
        return h;
    } else if (i == 3) {
        head.className = "";
        i -= 3;
        var h = i;
        return h;
    }
```

i = 3 is for assignment, i == 3 is for comparison.

Hope this helps

Lloyd

Comment: unfortunately, it now crashes after achieving last index of my array :/

Comment: what error do you get? and why is your else block check for == to 3?

Comment: max index in my array is 3, this function changes div class on click so when it reaches last element (3) I need to clear classes added before.

Comment: and the error i get is "name undefined" after reaching last element

Comment: ok i will change my last code block above, but you ultimately need to rethink what you are trying to achieve and revise this method. Remember head_class.length will be 0 while it is empty, unless you created it like this new Array(3)